# Is there way to render <table> horizontally when the list exceeds certain length?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html-table, visualization

I created a visualization with d3
http://jbk1109.github.io/tennisMapWithPlayersListOnHover.html

When mouse hovers over the histogram, a list appears underneath. There are a couple cases when the list becomes too long and I would like the table to grow horizontally beyond certain length.

Is there an optimal way to do this other than checking the length of list and appending a new table element?
[image]

Comment: you can always provide scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

Nice job Brian! I would try to get viewport height with jQuery, and compare it witch table height, something like:

```
if(table_height > viewport_height) {
    // change table css style to 2 column table
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul. If you don't mind, could you be specific about which CSS style attribute you are referring to? Just wondering if there is a way to split one table in CSS? Right now, my table is two columns (two <td> ).

Comment: Please shar your code on https://jsfiddle.net/ so i can reffer to it, and help you ;]